# Unable to find medium containing live file system

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

While installing Ubuntu, I got a message:

```
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
(initramfs)
```

I would also like to know what type of HDD is required for installing Ubuntu. `Basic` or `Dynamic`..

Comment: I AM USING HP15AC152TX DOS BASED  LAPTOP

Comment: There's no need to shout; the acoustics in here are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

> what type of HDD is required for installing Ubuntu. Basic or Dynamic?

The answer is `Basic`.

**Basic Disk** is supported by all Linux OSs .

**Dynamic Disk** is supported in Windows 2000 and later operating system **only**.

> "Unable to find medium containing live file system"

Please follow instructions given in the following links to create a proper bootable USB

- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)